# Age of post the cause of the wrong answer being upvoted/popular

Tags: discussion

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220357/qt-how-to-bind-a-qlist-to-a-qsqlquery-with-a-where-in-clause?answertab=active#tab-top) post currently have 3 answers in 2010 Travis concluded that the question did not have an answer and a bunch of people upvoted his conclusion.

However a few years later, two users did post working answers. But because of the popularity of the 'wrong' answer it still remained on top and looks like the best answer(because of all the votes)...

Why should we lose rep if you try to down-vote the popular answer in favor of the correct answer(s)?

Comment: If you don't want to downvote, you can at least upvote the answers you think are useful.  Maybe leave a comment on the accepted answer to point out there is a way?

Comment: Also if an old answer is wrong you should provide more than a link to the documentation and also explain what has changed making the answer wrong.

Comment: I understand you won't go downvoting every wrong answer you see. But if your downvote will make such a positive contribution, it's a small price to pay

Answer (score 2):

That question is *old*.

At time of writing, that answer was correct. Why should some lose rep on a answer that was correct *years* ago?

Just upvote the other answers.